# How does can I databind attributes of an associated class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have recently started to learn WPF.

I have created a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name ="Customers" Margin="0 8 0 0"  CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="KNr" IsReadOnly ="True" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding forename}" Header="Vorname" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding street}" Header="Straße" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding postal}" Header="PLZ" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding city}" Header="Stadt" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

```
        public test2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            CustomerAdress ca = new CustomerAdress("musterstr.1", "80335", "münchen");
            customers.Add(new Customer(Customer.Title.Herr, "mustermann", "max" , new DateTime(1920, 1, 1), ca, null));


            Customers.ItemsSource = customers;
        }
    }
```

So an instance of `Customer` references an instance of `CustomerAdress`. How can I databind the attributes of `CustomerAdress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is set as a `Customer` so simply access it by the `CustomerAddress` property within.

Example

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerAddress.street}" Header="Straße" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120"/>
```

I don't know what name you gave to the `CustomerAddress` property in your `Customer` class, but use the assigned name in your binding not the type name if it's different.